# How to create symbolic link to a file in root folder using cleartool command?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have a file in root location:

```
M:\My_View\Data.doc
```

I want the same file to be also visible in another folder, pointing to the file that is in the root location, using `cleartool` commands:

```
M:\My_View\Documents\Data.doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly, since [`cleartool ln -s`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_create_slink_vob.htm) is for a *Vob* symbolic link, meaning it works for elements within a Vob.
See also "[About creating Symbolic Links (symlinks) from command line](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260645)".

`M:\My_View\Data.doc` is not within a Vob (it is in a dynamic View, but only the first folder within that view, like Documents, is a Vob)

Comment: On top of that, it should not be possible to put a file in the root of a view. If it is, something is broken.